# Where can I find the sudo commands to work on the ubuntu grub file?

Tags: command-line, sudo

I am a newbie and need help with the sudo command. I am trying to edit the grub.cfg file via the etc\default\grub. The problem is that I don't know the sudo commands, particulary, the permission command and how to use. I'm planning on changing the boot menu to my satisfaction. This would include the order of the menu options, boders, colers and etc.

Comment: **Just an advice:** If you don't *exactly* know how to `sudo` you should not use it. One bad command can leave you with a completely broken system. Take care, it happened to a lot of people before.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `sudo` command and with whichever program you want to use to open the file. This looks like:

```bash
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

It asks for a password. Type your password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

`gedit` is a text editor.

You can also use grub-customizer. It's a GUI utility to customize GRUB.

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Comment: If you're new enough to ask this question, listen to Sudheer, install grub-customizer, and use it rather than directly edit the config file.

Comment: @Sudheer How to open customizer, now that I followed your sudo commands?

Comment: if you installed it then open dash(press windows key on keyboard) and type grub customizer you can see a penguin with gear symbol thats grub customizer

Comment: I have uninstalled Ubuntu and installed Zorin along side W7. Went well.I installed grub customizer and would like to know how to open it so I can change the menu in grub.cfg.

Comment: grub-customizer is the command

Comment: I"m back in Ubuntu. Loaded the grb customizer as directed. Re-alghn the menu order and add 100 minutes to timeout. Both work correctly. I the change colors of menun items and provide a background. Shows on screen as I edit this page. Save the changes, wait for the update to complete and restart to see my handiwork. The color and background change did NOT appear.Any ideas?